# Keras/TensorFlow low accuracy and val_acc

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am new in ML and I am doing a project using MobileNet mobel and Keras Sequential. I am doing multiclass classification, and I do not know why I am receiving such bad acc. My dataset has more than 20000 images, I divided into 80% for training, 10% validation and 10% test. Ps. I tried implementing learning rate schedules but it did not help. This is the code that I use for the model:

```
base_model=tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV2(input_shape=IMG_SHAPE,
include_top=False,
weights='imagenet')
feature_batch=base_model(image_batch)
base_model.trainable=False
global_average_layer=tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()
feature_batch_average=global_average_layer(feature_batch)
print(feature_batch_average.shape)
prediction_layer=keras.layers.Dense(7, activation='softmax')
prediction_batch=prediction_layer(feature_batch_average)
model=tf.keras.Sequential([base_model,
global_average_layer,
prediction_layer])
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, amsgrad=False),
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
initial_epochs=20
steps_per_epoch=round(len(train_images_set))//BATCH_SIZE
validation_steps=20
loss0,accuracy0 = model.evaluate(validation_batches, steps = validation_steps)
print("initial loss: {:.2f}".format(loss0))
print("initial accuracy: {:.2f}".format(accuracy0))
history = model.fit(train_batches,
                    epochs=initial_epochs,
                    validation_data=validation_batches)
```

Comment: What is bad accuracy? What is it, exactly, on each set? You need all of them to make conclusions.

Also, it the distribution of classes is not roughly equal, i.e. the dataset is unbalanced, you will have to generate more data for underrepresented class(es).

Comment: The accuracy per each epochs is less than 50% and the val_acc is less than 40%.

Comment: Is the data set balanced? It is very difficult to say where the problem might be. What kind of images are you using? or try to remove the pooling layer and try with more hidden layers instead.

Comment: Can you please confirm if the error is resolved with the comment mentioned above? Else, can you please share complete reproducible code so that we can help you.Thanks!

Comment: @TensorflowWarriors I resolved the error. The problem was my dataset, it was very bad. I had to manually preprocess it.

Comment: That's good to hear. Can you please elaborate on what exactly has resolved your problem for the benefit of the community.Thanks!

Comment: @TensorflowWarriors I mostly changed my whole approach to a multi label classification instead of multi class. What I was trying to predict was style related- so very subjective. Instead I went for a multi label approach: different labels to describe the style.